# Splunk: how to extract fields using regular expressions? like rex in splunk search

Tags: regex, splunk, rex

I want to extract Primary and StandyBy DB names from the below string which I found in my splunk search.

Jul 20 14:43:31 XXXXXXXX GuptaA  GuptaA - Primary database GuptaC - (*) Physical standby database GuptaB - Physical standby database.

Jul 20 14:43:31 XXXXXXXX KumarA KumarA - Primary database KumarC - (*) Physical standby database KumarD - Physical standby database - Physical standby database KumarE - Physical standby database

Primary DB : GuptaA
SecondaryDBs : GuptaC, GuptaB

I want to show a table with below details.

Primary DB            StandyByDB

GuptaA                  GuptaC, GuptaB
KumarA                 KumarC, KumarD, KumarE

Any suggestions using splunk search?

Thank you!

Comment: Please check if this helps. I had same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44689711/5912209

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rex field=_raw "Primary Database (?<primary>\S+) .* standby database (?<standby>\S+)"
| table primary standby
```