# How to use rex command to extract two fields and chart the count for both in one search query?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, rex

I have a log statement like 2017-06-21 12:53:48,426 INFO transaction.TransactionManager.Info:181 -{"message":{"TransactionStatus":true,"TransactioName":"removeLockedUser-1498029828160"}} . 
How can i extract TransactionName and TranscationStatus and print in table form TransactionName and its count.

I tried below query but didn't get any success. It is always giving me 0.

sourcetype=10.240.204.69 "TransactionStatus" | rex field=_raw ".TransactionStatus (?.)" |stats count((status=true)) as success_count

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with this :

| makeresults 
 | eval _raw="2017-06-21 12:53:48,426 INFO transaction.TransactionManager.Info:181 -{\"message\":{\"TransactionStatus\":true,\"TransactioName\":\"removeLockedUser-1498029828160\"}}"
 | rename COMMENT AS "Everything above generates sample event data; everything below is your solution"
 | rex "{\"TransactionStatus\":(?[^,]*),\"TransactioName\":\"(?[^\"]*)\""
 | chart count OVER TransactioName BY TransactionStatus